# Cert manager update using helm failes everytime

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, azure-aks

**Context**
I am working on a task to renew SSL Let's Encrypt certificates since they've expired unexpectedly a few days ago.The servers I'm working with are on Azure AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) and SSL is configured with Azure Application Gateway. We had set up cert-manager using helm for automatic certs renewal. we've set up ca injector, and a manager webhook for MutatingWebhookConfiguration and ValidatingWebhookConfiguration.

**Versions:**
Helm version: 3.9.3
cert-manager version: 0.13.0
AKS version: 1.27.7

This is what's configured in the cert-manager namespace.

```
NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE 
cert-manager              1/1     1            1           
cert-manager-cainjector   0/1     1            0          
cert-manager-webhook      1/1     1            1
```

The CA injector throws the following error in logs:

```
1 start.go:82] starting ca-injector v0.13.0 (revision 6d9200f9d)
1 start.go:147] error registering core-only controllers: no matches for kind "MutatingWebhookConfiguration" in version "admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

output of describe command is the following:

```
k describe po ca-injector
```

```
Name:             cert-manager-cainjector-123
Namespace:        cert-manager
Priority:         0
Service Account:  cert-manager-cainjector
Node:             aks-agentpool-vmss
Start Time:       Fri, 09 Feb 2024 13:17:19 +0100
Labels:           app=cainjector
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=cert-manager
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=cainjector
                  helm.sh/chart=cert-manager-v0.13.0
                  pod-template-hash=nb
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               IP-address
IPs:
  IP:           pod-ip-here
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/cert-manager-cainjector-1234
Containers:
  cert-manager:
    Container ID:  containerd:
    Image:         quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-cainjector:v0.13.0
    Image ID:      quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-cainjector@sha256:46f539739694d01cb058dac7f37d7160689f9933825e179ec46a08a6b6f681de
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      --v=2
      --leader-election-namespace=kube-system
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 09 Feb 2024 13:43:52 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 09 Feb 2024 13:43:53 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  10
    Environment:
      POD_NAMESPACE:  cert-manager (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-hmlfw (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-hmlfw:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  31m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned cert-manager/cert-manager-cainjector-123 to aks-agentpool
  Normal   Pulling    31m                  kubelet            Pulling image "quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-cainjector:v0.13.0"
  Normal   Pulled     31m                  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-cainjector:v0.13.0" in 1.736009777s (1.736016777s including waiting)
  Normal   Created    29m (x5 over 31m)    kubelet            Created container cert-manager
  Normal   Started    29m (x5 over 31m)    kubelet            Started container cert-manager
  Normal   Pulled     29m (x4 over 31m)    kubelet            Container image "quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-cainjector:v0.13.0" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    73s (x139 over 31m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container cert-manager in pod cert-manager-cainjector_cert-manager(..)
```

**What I have done so far**
I tried to upgrade the cert-manager version using helm cmd :

```
helm upgrade cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --set installCRDs=true --set version=1.11.5
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from current release manifest: [resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-cainjector" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-issuers" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-clusterissuers" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-certificates" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-orders" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-challenges" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-ingress-shim" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRole" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-cainjector" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-issuers" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-clusterissuers" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-certificates" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-orders" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-challenges" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-controller-ingress-shim" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-webhook:auth-delegator" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-cainjector:leaderelection" namespace: "kube-system" from "": no matches for kind "Role" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager:leaderelection" namespace: "kube-system" from "": no matches for kind "Role" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-cainjector:leaderelection" namespace: "kube-system" from "": no matches for kind "RoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager:leaderelection" namespace: "kube-system" from "": no matches for kind "RoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-webhook:webhook-authentication-reader" namespace: "kube-system" from "": no matches for kind "RoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-webhook" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "MutatingWebhookConfiguration" in version "admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "cert-manager-webhook" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "ValidatingWebhookConfiguration" in version "admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first]
```

I have checked all the CRDs, roles, rolebindings, clusterroles and clusterrolebindings versions to make sure they're up to date.All of the validation and mutation CRDs are on .k8s.io/v1.

I've also tried installing the CRDs before upgrading certs-manager. I got an error when applying the patch.

I am a bit confused on what to do next, I've seen on a different thread people tend to delete all the CRDs and reinstall and reconfigure cert-manager and secrets etc.. not sure if that's the right approach as it sounds risky even with a backup.

How would you recommend I approach this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-install `cert-manager` CRDs separately before upgrading/installing Helm.

```bash
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.11.5/cert-manager.crds.yaml
```

Then, upgrade `cert-manager` without Helm handling CRDs.

```bash
helm upgrade cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --namespace cert-manager --version=1.11.5
```

If the above is not working, You might need to re-install `cert-manager`

> In some cases there may be a need to do a full uninstall and re-install of cert-manager. An example could be when a very old cert-manager version needs to be brought up to date and it isn't feasible to upgrade one minor version at a time, which is our default recommended upgrade strategy.

Docs: https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/reinstall/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I got an error when applying CRD patch before upgrading. there seems to be a config mismatch of some sort (long error very unclear). I will try reinstalling cert-manager.